# Drop a dimension of a tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice, tensor

I have a tensor that have shape `(50, 100, 1, 512)` and i want to reshape it or drop the third dimension so that the new tensor have shape `(50, 100, 512)`.

I have tried `tf.slice` with `tf.squeeze`:

```
a = tf.slice(a, [50, 100, 1, 512], [50, 100, 1, 512])
b = tf.squeeze(a)
```

Everything seem working when i tried to print the shape of `a` and `b` but when i start training my model this error came

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected size[0] in [0, 0], but got 50
     [[Node: Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](MaxPool_2, Slice/begin, Slice/size)]]
```

Are there any problem with my `slice`. How can i fix it. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried .reshape()? Also does the dimension hold any value? It would unwise to slice data that's needed. Not a practice I've seen before.

Comment: @Kenpachi: I haven't tried .reshape() but that dimension is not important so I wanted to drop it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally `tf.squeeze` will drop the dimensions.

```
a = tf.constant([[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]])
```

The above tensor shape is `[1,2,3]`. After performing squeeze operation,

```
b = tf.squeeze(a)
```

Now, Tensor shape is `[2,3]`

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple ways to do it. Tensorflow has started supporting indexing. Try

```
a = a[:, :, 0, :]
```

**OR**

```
a = a[:, :, -1, :]
```

**OR**

```
a = tf.reshape(a, [50, 100, 512])
```

**OR**

```
a = tf.squeeze(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the `tf.slice` wrong in this case, it's should be like this:

```
a = tf.slice(a, [0, 0, 0, 0], [50, 100, 1, 512])
b = tf.squeeze(a)
```

You can find out why by look at the `tf.slice` [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice)

Comment: Why even use `slice` at all? Simply using `squeeze` should do the job.

Comment: @xdurch0 I thought `squeeze` only remove dim with size = 1